# Set content's as container

Tags: css, responsive

Is it possible to set width this same like container in css? OK, I'll display you my problem. I want to make side responsive  menu which will be hide in mobile and visible on Desktop. So, I want to main content (on mobile) have width like their container and I will use translate in order to hide menu. For example

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    transform: translateX(-150px);
}
.menu {
    width: 150px;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I know that in JS it's possible to check container with and change `.content` width dinamically but I want to know that is better way to realize that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to change the with dynamically based on screen size.
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) is the documentation on MDN, but probably something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    /* Here are styles for screens equal to or narrower than 500px */
}
```

Comment: I know that of course. But it doesn't solve my problem becouse in this way I could't have all the time this same width with container and content.

Comment: So your main case is to hide the menu in mobile view right? Why don't you use display: none for the .menu with media queries which Riley mentioned above?

Comment: Becouse I want to animate the slide-out'slide-in effect of the menu on mobile.

Comment: Would it work to add the animation property inside the media query?

Comment: Yes, I can, and I want do that but I want to animate all container with content and menu. I want to have silder effect, when part of content is not visible, if menu is open. So I need to have width of wrapper.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense now. I don't know if you can do that in CSS.